# Prove or disprove: The minimum number of transpositions needed to decompose $\sigma$ is $n-S$.

Tags: permutations, cyclic-decomposition

Assume that $\sigma \in S_n$ and $\sigma = \alpha_1 \dots\alpha_s$ is the decomposition of $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles, such that all of the members of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are appeared in the members of $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_s$.

Is this statement true?

> The minimum number of transpositions needed to decompose $\sigma$ is $n-S$.

Comment: I'm curious as to where you found this. Do you have any references? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true because every cycle of length $k$ can be decomposed as the product of $k-1$ transpositions. The way to see that is to observe that 
$$(1,2,\ldots,k)= (1,2)(2,3)\ldots(k-1,k)$$
which can be checked directly from the formula (each $i$ goes to $i+1$ modulo $k$)

Answer (score 14):

amakelov explains why $n-S$ transpositions are sufficient. To show that $n-S$ transpositions are necessary, one proves that for a permutation $\sigma$ and a transposition $\tau$, $\sigma\tau$ has one more, or one fewer cycle than $\sigma$. As the identity permutation has $n$ cycles, a product of $k$ transpositions has at least $n-k$ cycles. So if $k<n-S$,
a product of $k$ transpositions has more than $S$ cycles.

Comment: thanks! totally missed the other direction. that's very neat

Answer (score 0):

$d=n-s$ is called the decrement of the permutation $\sigma$. It **not always** is equal to the minimal number of transpositions needed to write $\sigma$.

**Example.** Assume for simplicity $n=2$, i.e., we are in $S_2$. The identity permutation $e=(1)(2)$ is of degree $n=2$, and it has $2$ disjoint cycles. Hence its decrement is $d=2-2=0$. But $e$ **cannot** be written by zero transpositions.

By definition a transposition is a permutation of type $(ij)$, and hence we have to write, say, $e=(12)(12)$. At least **two** transpositions are needed. You cannot write, say, $e=e$ and call it transpositions decomposition by **zero** transpositions because $e$ is not a transposition.

By the way, for this very same reason we in the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic require that the integer $n$ must be **greater** than $1$ to have a decomposition as a product of primes. For, the equality $1=1$ cannot be interpreted as a product of **zero** primes.

My students had seen this page and discussed the issue with me. Hence I add this remark here.